# poor performance of scrollview inside tableview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory, uiscrollview

I have trouble with table view and its response because every cell has scrollView with 72 labels in it. I know that scrollView needs to load all elements first, and than load on screen, and because of that table view is slow, but is there a way maybe not to allocate and call initWithFrame method every time I create label? I tried to reuse label with different frame, but it is not working.

Here is code I need to optimize somehow to create labels faster.

```
    int listSize = 36;

    for(int i=0;i<listSize;i++){
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0+i*200, 0, 200, 80)];
        label.text = @"HELLO";
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18];
        [scrolView addSubview:label];

        UILabel *grayBorderInFront = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2+i*200, 5, 1, scrolView.frame.size.height-10)];
        grayBorderInFront.text = @"";
        grayBorderInFront.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [scrolView addSubview:grayBorderInFront];
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achive? Maybe if you show us some code we can help you.

Comment: I want my data to be scrollable in scroll view (left and right), but also I want to scroll down trough list view. But for now it is too slow when I go down or up.

Comment: Instead of creating new labels for each cell, you should subclass UITableViewCell, and just reset the text as your table scrolls.  You can override `prepareForReuse` to reset your cells to a default state, and then just set the text of the labels for that row.

Comment: Put only the visible labels into the view.  Then implement the delegate function `scrollviewdidscroll` and create new labels if they need to become visible.

Answer (score 0):

Save your labels in an array and then add them just to the view. Or you could even cache the whole scrollview.

Edit:
You keep a list of values that are updating. For all the labels created in the scrollview you set a tag label1.tag = 4; (starting from 1 instead of zero because 0 is the default one and other views have it as well).

Then, in your cellForViewAtIndexPath instead of creating a new label every time, you get the labels with [cell viewWithTag:] and you get a reference of the label. The only thing you have to do is to change the value of the label. You can also use the tag as index in the array:

```
int index = 3; // third label
[(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:index+1] setText:[myLabelsArray objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Comment: I have created 72 labels just for test. I need some data from server, and number of labels will be random number, so I can't create array.

Comment: Each time I enter that view I receive update from server and display content. List and scroll will not refresh after a period of time.

Comment: yes my suggestion is to cache the objects, so you don't have to de/allocate them all the time. you still can change their values...

Comment: I tried to create array of labels, but now they are not showing. I can see labels only in 1 scrollView at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have one TableView and eachCell has a horizontal CollectionView.

Set the scroll direction property to horizontal and use the [UIViewCollectionFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewFlowLayout/scrollDirection)

The CollectionView will guarantee that your labels (that are cells) are being reused and that you are doing an efficient job.

Comment: I know that but, my requirement is iOS 5.

Comment: Hmm, you can also use an horizontal tableview - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834840/how-to-make-a-horizontal-ui-table-view-on-iphone

Comment: Basic idea is to create EPG that have image of cannel on left, and scrollable section on right so user can scroll trough timeline and see program. I don't need whole table to scroll, only 1 part (scrollView in each cell).

Comment: Folks ported CollectionView for iOS 4.3 (maybe it even works in iOS 4.0, i don't tested it): https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView

Answer (score 0):

Few weeks ago I implemented EPG layout for iPhone app using collectionView with custom layout.
On the iPad app other developer implemented the EPG with scrollView with array of collectionView flow layout.

The custom layout work mach better.

You mentioned that you need iOS 5 hence you can try the following open source replacement to collection view:
https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView